# Distribution of Piecewise Random Variable (CDF Technique)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Let $T\sim EXP(1/\mu)\implies E(T)=1/\mu\implies f(t)=\mu e^{-\mu t}$

Define $Y:=$
\begin{cases}
(1-v^T)/\delta,  & \text{if 0 < T < n} \\
(1-v^n)/\delta, & \text{if T $\ge$ $n$ }
\end{cases}

where $\delta\in[1,\infty), v\in(0,1),\mu\in(0,\infty)$

Basically, a limit has been put on $Y$.

What is the CDF of $Y$?  In other words, what is $P(Y\le y)$?

I don't think that the CDF technique will work here, but I'm not sure.  How can you get this CDF?

Comment: Did you intend your first line to say $T\sim EXP(1/\mu)\implies E(T)=\mu$ ?

Comment: @Henry, no, I clarified what I meant with an edit.

Comment: Yes the CDF technique should still work. First you deal with the first piece and compute the CDF. The second piece is just a constant, so you have a discrete mass at that point which correspond to a jump discontinuity in CDF.